# Library for generating HD keys/addresses (ideally for python)

Tags: testnet, python, bip32-hd-wallets, library

I require a library that I can create (and later import) a HD master key, which I will use to generate hundreds of addresses for both testnet and mainnet!

Ideally, I need a python library (but had trouble of finding a good library for both testnet and mainnet addresses.

An example of how to create testnet addresses would be greatly appreciated (default functionality seems to be for mainnet, e.g. pybitcointools)

Good libraries for other languages are also very welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Actually python library [pycoin](https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin) seems to be sufficient for both testnet and mainnet address. I had just missed it the first time I checked the library.

It also provides a powerful command line tool.

Answer (score 1):

Also excellent commentary about pycoin on Richard Kiss's Blog [On BIP0032 and Bitcoin Deterministic Wallets](http://blog.richardkiss.com/?p=313)

Then also there is Vitalik Buterin's [Pybitcointools](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools)

Where these commands exist:

```
    bip32_master_key : (seed) -> bip32 master key
    bip32_ckd : (private or public bip32 key, i) -> child key
    bip32_privtopub : (private bip32 key) -> public bip32 key
    bip32_extract_key : (private or public bip32_key) -> privkey or pubkey
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also the 21 Bitcoin Library
https://21.co/learn/#reference-21-library